# IBM Worklight - How to pass parameters from the application to the adapter?

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I want to pass parameters from the application to the adapter; I want the users of the app to enter these options.

Right now I am passing the parameters like this in adapter:

```
    function getFeeds() {
        WL.Logger.debug("inside method");

        var input = {
            method : 'get',
            returnedContentType : 'json',
            path : "ios/clientRegister.php",
            parameters:{
              "employeenumber":"500","employeename":"Harish","employeeemail":"anand5@gmail.com","city":"Delhi", 
              "employeeadID":"an6458","businessUnit":"WASE","country":"India","city":"Bengaluru","location":"EC4","bloodGroup":"B+ve", "gender":"Male","tShirt":"xl"    
            }  
        };
        return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the parameters using simple JavaScript.
For example:

**HTML**

```
First name: <input type="text" id="firstname"/>
Last name: <input type="text" id="lastname"/>
<input type="button" onclick="submitName()" value="Submit Name"/>
```

**App JS**

```
function submitName() {
    var invocationData = {
            adapter : 'exampleAdapter',
            procedure : "showParameters",
            parameters : [$('#firstname').val(),$('#lastname').val()]
    };
    
    var options = {
            onSuccess : success,
            onFailure : failure
    };
    
    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, options);
}


function success() {
    alert ("success");
}

function failure() {
    alert ("failure");
}
```

**Adapter XML**

```
<procedure name="showParameters"/>
```

**Adapter implementation**

```
function showParameters(firstname, lastname) {
    WL.Logger.info  ("The submitted parameters are: '" + firstname + "' and '" + lastname + "'");
}
```

To actually see the logged line you'll need to:

1. Open the Servers view in Eclipse
2. Expend the `Worklight Development Server` entry
3. Double-click on `Server Configuration`
4. Click on `Logging`
5. Change the Console log leve from `AUDIT` to `INFO` (using the dropdown)

   Full size image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9llHc.png
   [image]
6. You may need to Project >> Clean...
7. The outcome will be in the Console view for the Worklight Development Server

   Full size image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2Hv1.png
   [image]

Comment: Please share the information on how to see the logged data/lines.
I have to use this in all other test cases to analyze the behaviour of the worklight.

Thanks a lot....

Comment: It depends on your Worklight version. What is your Worklight version? See my updated answer with instructions for Worklight 6.0. In any case, if my answer helped you understand how to pass parameters (which is what this question is about), please mark as Answered. Thanks!

Comment: Once again Thanks a lot for your valuable information Idan Adar.

Comment: How to use validation in the options and how to get drop down for one selected item(like we use spinners in android).

Comment: Not related to this question (nor to Worklight).

Comment: country: <input type="text" id="country"/> for this I want to have drop down menu. How to query the database in php. Plz share the information. Thanks.

Comment: Open a new question with the php tag. This is not related to Worklight. Comments are not meant for questions.