# Passing parameters through HTTP Adapter?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I want to send an email to the user after he/she sign's up in my hybrid application (based on IBM Worklight 6.0).

I want to pass the parameters (email ID) of the user to a PHP file hosted.  I tried directly to send a mail in the URL as Follows, and this works:

```
http://www.xxxyyyzzz.comli.com/email.php?a=someEmailAddress@someEmailHost.com
```

How to do the same via a Worklight adapter?

**ADAPTER.XML**

```
 <wl:adapter name="sendmail"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:wl="http://www.worklight.com/integration"
xmlns:http="http://www.worklight.com/integration/http">

<displayName>sendmail</displayName>
<description>sendmail</description>
<connectivity>
    <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <domain>xxxyyy.comli.com</domain>
        <port>80</port> 

        <sslCertificateAlias></sslCertificateAlias> 
        <sslCertificatePassword></sslCertificatePassword>
        -->     
    </connectionPolicy>
    <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="2" />
</connectivity>

<procedure name="getStories"/>

<procedure name="getStoriesFiltered"/>

 </wl:adapter>
```

**ADAPTER IMP.JS**

```
function getStories(interest) {
path = getPath(interest);

var input = {
    method : 'get',
    returnedContentType : 'html',
    path : '/email.php?a='
};


return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the parameter? You are not passing it to the adapter procedure AFAICT.
Try the below (I did not test it end-to-end, as I don't have a server with a PHP script listening to requests).

**HTML**

```
Your email address: <input type="text" id="emailaddr"/>
<input type="button" onclick="sendEmail()" value="Submit Email Address"/>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function sendEmail() {
    var invocationData = {
            adapter : 'myAdapter',
            procedure : 'sendEmailProcedure',
            parameters : [$('#emailaddr').val()] // the email adrress taken from the HTML...
    };

    var options = {
            onSuccess : success,
            onFailure : failure
    };

    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, options);
}

function success() {
    WL.Logger.debug ("invocation succeeded.");
}
function failure() {
    WL.Logger.debug ("invocation failed.");
}
```

**myAdapter.xml**

```
...
...
<connectivity>
    <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <domain>host-address</domain>
        <port>80</port> 
    </connectionPolicy>
    <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="2" />
</connectivity>

<procedure name="sendEmailProcedure"/>
```

**myAdapter-impl.js**

```
function sendEmailProcedure(emailAddress) {
    var input = {
        method : 'get',
        returnedContentType : 'html',
        path : '/email.php?a=' + emailAddress
    };

    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}
```

See related questions:

- [IBM Worklight - How to pass parameters from the application to the adapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17851867/ibm-worklight-how-to-pass-parameters-from-the-application-to-the-adapter/17852974#17852974)
- [IBM Worklight 6.1 - How to send post values in adapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21014983/ibm-worklight-6-1-how-to-send-post-values-in-adapter/21018022#21018022)

Comment: I passed the parameter during invocation. Tht is i tried invoking the adapter.

Comment: Your code snippet does not show any parameter passed to the adapter.

Comment: I tried invoking the adapter procedure manually by using run as-> invoke procedure and passed the paramter in the txt box

Comment: And when you try the above?

Comment: I tried after making minute changes after referring your code.. It works perfectly..