# Integrating Cloudant no sql-db by using Worklight Adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, cloudant, mobilefirst-adapters, nosql

I am following [Link](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.0/server-side-development/cloudant/) to integrate cloudant no sql-db in worklight adapter.

There are methods given create DB, Find all, count, search. All working fine. But how can I fire query like name=abc&age=23? Like in sql we use & operator to achieve that. So here how can I achieve this in one adapter call.

Below is URL for searching one item-

https://a59af583-6f36-47ea-a8ce-29df674a8442-bluemix.cloudant.com/employee_table/_design/indexes/_search/employee_table/?q=Employee_Name:Suhas~

Also below is one of the doc of may table 'employee_table' for reference -

```
{
     "_id": "0b6459f8d368db408140ddc09bb30d19",
     "_rev": "1-6fe6413eef59d0b9c5ab5344dc642bb1",
     "Reporting_Manager": "sdasd",
     "Designation": "asdasd",
     "Access_Level": 2,
     "Employee_ID": 123123,
     "Employee_Name": "Suhas",
     "Project_Name": "asdasd",
     "Password": "asda",
     "Location": "asdasd",
     "Project_Manager": "asdas"
}
```

Comment: @Idan Its related to worklight also. As I provided link also.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the parameters readily available, you can pass these in the `parameters` option of your invocationData. See here for a detailed explanation: [Passing parameters through HTTP Adapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21984676/passing-parameters-through-http-adapter)

For example:

```
var invocationData = {
        adapter : 'myAdapter',
        procedure : 'sendEmailProcedure',
        parameters : [$('#emailaddr').val()] // the email adrress taken from the HTML...
};
```