# Unable to call 'onSuccess' or 'onFailure' of adapter invocation

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I have an adapter which retrieves a JSON object, but strangely everything works fine if the form uses only button, but if I put `<input type="text">` then `WL.Client.invokeProcedure`'s callbacks ('onSuccess' or 'onFailure') or not called...

Adapter Code:

```
 intranetId="my-email-address";
 var invocationData = {
     adapter : 'RoleAdapter',
     procedure : 'getRoles',
     parameters : [intranetId,"role"]
};

WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
      onSuccess : function(res){ console.log('win', res); },
      onFailure : function(res){ console.log('fail', res); }
```

HTML Form:

```
<div id="welcome">
<form action="#welcome2" onsubmit="getRole()">
<input type="text" id="userId">
<br/>
<input type="password" name = "password">
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
</div>
```

I am able to get value of `userId`, and even if I hardcode it in `getRole()` same problem...

edit: 
On changing the html form to this

```
<div id="welcome">
<form action="#welcome2" onsubmit="return getRole()">
<input type="submit" value="go">
</form>
</div>
```

I tried debugging, but cudnt get anything.

edit2:
I fixed it!
So basically, In html form you cannot add 'name' property to an input element when you are using with worklight. Don't know why it is so..

Comment: Can you supply **full** functions instead of *incomplete* code snippets?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me...
Full example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17852974/1530814

**index.html**

```
<form onsubmit="submitName()">
    First name: <input type="text" id="firstname"/><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" id="lastname"/><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Name"/>
</form>
```

**main.js**

```
function wlCommonInit(){

}

function submitName() {
    var invocationData = {
            adapter : 'exampleAdapter',
            procedure : "showParameters",
            parameters : [$('#firstname').val(),$('#lastname').val()]
    };

    var options = {
            onSuccess : success,
            onFailure : failure
    };

    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, options);
}


function success() {
    alert ("success");
}

function failure(res) {
    alert ("failure");
}
```

Comment: I tried with your style of calling the WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, options);
as well, but didnot work.
but as mentioned above if I change the html form like this everything works like butter,
`<div id="welcome">
<form action="#welcome2" onsubmit="return getRole()">
<input type="submit" value="go">
</form>
</div>`